# How to create stages for AWS state machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have created a simple AWS state machine with lambda functions. Like below

```
{
  "Comment":"Validates data",
  "StartAt": "ChooseDocumentType",
  "States": {
    "ChooseDocumentType": {      
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices":[
        {
          "Variable":"$.documentType",
          "StringEquals":"RETURN",
          "Next":"ValidateReturn"
        },
        {
          "Variable":"$.documentType",
          "StringEquals":"ASSESSMENT",
          "Next":"ValidateAssessment"
        }        
      ],
      "Default":"DefaultState"
    },
    "ValidateReturn":{
      "Type":"Task",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateReturn",
      "Next":"DefaultState"
    },
     "ValidateAssessment":{
      "Type":"Task",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateAssessment",
      "Next":"DefaultState"
    },
    "DefaultState":{
      "Type":"Pass",      
      "End":true
    }
  }
}
```

**Questions**
1> How do i create stages for this state machine. (like production, development etc)?

2>Each lambda function has `alias` pointing to different versions. So `development` alias always point to `$latest` version and `production` alias point to, lets say, version `2`. How do i dynamically associate state machine's stages with these lambda alias? So state machine in `development` stage should use lambda function with alias `development` and so on.

I am using AWS console to manage state machines and lambdas, and i don't see any action to create stages for state machine

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the alias and the version in the Lambda [ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases-permissions.html):

```
# default, $LATEST
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateAssessment

# using alias
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateAssessment:development

# using version
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateAssessment:2
```

Use these in the Step Function definition according to your needs.

Comment: Yes, but alias or version is hardcoded here. how do you use variables for alias? So for example in AWS API Gateway you can invoke lambda using variable as `arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111:function:ValidateAssessment:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` where `lambdaAlias` is a variable defined in api stage. The value of `lambdaAlias` will different in each stage. How do i apply the same kind of concept in step functions?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Step Functions. I would create two (or more) separate Step Functions, one for development and one for production stage. Alternatively, if you want to have it all in a single SF, you could have flag in the payload that you start the SF with and build the state machine with two branches. Add a Choice state at the beginning that looks at the payload and decides based on that which branch to execute; similar to the `documentType` Choice in your SF.

Answer (score 0):

Re: # 2, if your main concern is controlling which Lambda alias gets invoked, there is a way you can do that via a single step function.

Your step function state definition would be something like:

```
{  
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
   "Parameters": {  
      "InvocationType": "RequestResponse",
      "FunctionName": "someFunction",
      "Qualifier.$": "$.lambdaAlias",
      "Payload": {}
   },
}
```

So where you execute the step function and would specify the stage if there was such a thing, you'd pass a `lambdaAlias` parameter. (There's nothing magical about that name, you can pull it from whatever step function input parameter you want.)

The request payload to your Lambda would go in `Parameters.Payload`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html